# Calculating percentage change of a column in two consecutive rows using AWK

Tags: shell, awk

Need to the calculate % change between consecutive values in second column of a data file using `awk`.

The data file looks like -

```
-bash-4.2$ cat coun11.csv
16-SEP-21,4218596
17-SEP-21,3747178
```

Since the number of rows will remain fixed, i.e., 2, I don't want to use `while` with `read` to loop over the file, instead I want to use a single line statement `awk`, if possible.

The more i read on it in relation with `awk`, it seemed possible but didn't get the desired result.

Answer should `11.2%` (can be negative) i.e., rounded off by one decimal place for which we can use `OFMT` i believe.

% diff should always be calculated with `((oldvalue-newvalue)/oldvalue)*100`, wherein oldvalue refers to first row and newvalue to second row, which is evident from dates in first column.

One of the used commands `awk 'BEGIN { NF==1?a=$2:b=$2}{c=(((a-b)/a)*100)} END {OFMT="%f";print c}' coun11.csv`, which didn't work

Comment: update the question to show the `awk` code you tried and the (wrong) result generated by said code; also provide the calculation you're using to obtain the value (eg, line1/line2, 100-(line2/line1)) and what to do with negative values (leave negative or `abs()` to generate a positive number)

Comment: Why is your desired output positive?

Comment: @markp-fuso i am using [((oldvalue-newvalue)/oldvalue)*100]. One of the command i tried but didn't work `awk 'BEGIN { NF==1?a=$2:b=$2}{c=(((a-b)/a)*100)} END {OFMT="%f";print c}' coun11.csv`
@WilliamPursell Its not, I just mentioned the value. It can be negative.

Answer (score 1):

OP's current code:

```
awk 'BEGIN { NF==1?a=$2:b=$2}{c=(((a-b)/a)*100)} END {OFMT="%f";print c}' coun11.csv
```

A few problems:

- `BEGIN {...}` processing is performed before the file is opened/read so ...
- `NF=0` within the `BEGIN {...}` block so ...
- `a` and `b` are undefined coming out of the `BEGIN {...}` block (**NOTE:** in `awk` undefined variables have a default value of 0)
- `NF` refers to the number of fields in the current line but OP is looking to process specific lines 1 & 2 so ...
- I'm guessing OP wants to use the `FNR` (aka line number of current record) instead
- for each line read from the file `awk` tries to apply `c=(((a-b)/a)*100)`, but since `a==b==0` OP should be getting an error (eg, `... fatal: division by zero attempted`)
- the calculation should only be performed once and can either be performed as part of processing the 2nd line (`FNR==2`) or simply moved to the `END {...}` block
- `OFMT="%f"` is not going to generate the desired output format of `11.2%`; while OP has mentioned 2 decimal places the expected output only shows 1 decimal place; we'll look at formats to generate both; after that OP is free to experiment with `OFMT` as needed

One idea for some edits (and assuming OPs calculation is correct):

```
awk -F',' '
FNR==1 { a=$2 }
FNR==2 { b=$2 }
END    { c=(((a-b)/a)*100)
         printf "%.1f%\n", c             # 1 decimal place
       }
' coun11.csv

# or as a single line

awk -F',' 'FNR==1{a=$2}FNR==2{b=$2} END{c=(((a-b)/a)*100); printf "%.1f%\n", c}' coun11.csv

# using ternary for the test/assignment:

awk -F',' '
       { (FNR==1) ? (a=$2) : (b=$2) }   # if FNR > 2 b will be overwritten with latest field #2
END    { c=(((a-b)/a)*100)
         printf "%.1f%\n", c 
}
' coun11.csv

# or as a single line

awk -F',' '{(FNR==1)?(a=$2):(b=$2)} END{c=(((a-b)/a)*100); printf "%.1f%\n", c}' coun11.csv
```

All of these generate:

```
11.2%
```

For 2 decimal places we want `printf "%.2f%\n",c` which generates:

```
11.17%
```

Comment: Seems I messed up on several avenues! 
I need to study more to remove the confusion with `FNR`, `NR`, `NF`, etc. and understand how that works. Adding `BEGIN` was a mistake assuming that the code needs to perform one set of tasks AFTER it starts reading the file.

Comment: @vkeeWork good news ... you spelled `awk` correctly! :-)  `awk '{print NR,FNR}' coun11.csv coun11.csv` to see `NR` and `FNR` in action

Comment: lol.. but yeah reading about it will clear the concepts further. Actually there was another file but with different ask to check if the values in second column are above a certain threshold for particular rows and I tried with following command and it works perfectly : `awk -F',' '{(FNR==1)?(($3>=600)?(a=1):(a=0)):(($3>=500000)?(b=1):(b=0))} END{if (a!=0 && b!=0) print "Under Threshold"; else print "Threshold Breached";}' count8.csv` 

I really like using `awk` as it helps to write single line commands wherein otherwise it would require multiline code.

Comment: @vkeeWork I can see at a glance there's a much simpler, clearer way to write the code in your comment but I don't know if what you have is accurate code or not as there's no associated [mcve]. In any case, [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged so if you have a question about that new problem, then just ask a new question.

Comment: @EdMorton I didn't really get you about the first point. The file content is there and I also added the command i tried as it was pointed out. Also about the second part, I didn't ask another question, rather just shared what i learned and applied. Didn't even ask to review/verify it. Is that wrong?!

Comment: @vkeeWork the file content is where? All you provided in the comment was code, no sample input and no expected output. Not sure why you posted that code if not for us to look at it and provide feedback - I'm just saying it could be significantly improved on and if you want help with it then ask a question.

Comment: Gosh! you were referring to the command in comment [face palm]. 
As i said, it is working perfectly and since the dataset is miniscule, not sure if further optimization is required. Readability can be improved, I do agree with that.

Comment: Yes, I did say it was about `...the code in your comment`. FWIW a clearer, simpler way to write that code would, I think, be `awk -F',' '{v[NR]=$3} END{print (v[1]>=600 && v[2]>=50000 ? "Under Threshold" : "Threshold Breached")}' count8.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your calculation is a bit off.  I would do:

```
printf "foo %d\n" 4218596 3747178 4218596 |
awk 'NR>1 {printf "%.1f\n", ($2/d) * 100 - 100} {d=$2}'
```

Comment: It also only works for a CSV file of two lines.

Comment: @jjramsey My initial comment was incorrect about converting END to NR>1, but this solution handles multiple rows.

Comment: Added the formula for further clarification. I thought % change calculation is a generic formula and everyone would know it

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box, this will work for all pairs of contiguous lines in the input:

```
$ awk -F',' 'NR>1{printf "%.1f\n", (prev ? ((prev - $2) / prev) * 100 : 0)} {prev = $2}' coun11.csv
11.2
```

Make sure to test any potential solution using this input:

```
$ cat foo.csv
16-SEP-21,0
17-SEP-21,3747178
```

to make sure it doesn't produce a divide-by-zero error (which the ternary expression `(prev ? ((prev - $2) / prev) * 100 : 0)` in my answer protects against):

```
$ awk -F',' 'NR>1{printf "%.1f\n", (prev ? ((prev - $2) / prev) * 100 : 0)} {prev = $2}' foo.csv
0.0
```

Alternatively since you only have 2 lines of input you could do:

```
$ awk -F',' 'prev{rslt=((prev - $2) / prev) * 100} {prev = $2} END{printf "%.1f\n", rslt}' coun11.csv
11.2

$ awk -F',' 'prev{rslt=((prev - $2) / prev) * 100} {prev = $2} END{printf "%.1f\n", rslt}' foo.csv
0.0
```

Comment: Correct, the sheet will always have two rows and two columns. That divide-by-0 check is a nice check and prevents breaks in code while execution, but this is pre-checked actually before the file is available in the landing location. There's a separate job which does the sanity check on all the files received from source and filters out those with 0 in data column as per business requirement.

Comment: @vkeeWork that sounds a lot like one of those "it'll never happen so we don't have to protect against it" decisions that almost always comes back to bite you 2 years later in the field with live data. Divide-by-zero is a trivial thing to protect against with typically very bad consequences if you don't and it happens so it's best to just build it into your code.

Comment: Yes, included it. 
Just making the point that file with 0 in data field will never make it to the landing location as it'll be filtered out based on the exact check i.e., 0 in any data fields.